# Asp .net mvc: async controller method blocks incoming requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

In asp .net MVC project I'm trying to call controller's Get method with some long lasting operation asynchronously. The problem is that after first call other incoming requests are waiting when this operation will be finished. And after that they are handled one by one in order they were requested.

Tested on code below.
So if for example I make requests to SomeGetMethod multiple times, for the incoming request this method will be executed only when SomeGetMethod finished for previous call.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> SomeGetMethod(int id)
    {
        await TestAsync();
        return Content("1");
    }


    public async Task<int> TestAsync()
    {

        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(20000));

        return 1;
    }
}
```

What might be the reason of that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use Task.Delay i stead of Thread.Sleep when doing async stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Task.Run could be executed on the same thread as your controller, so you should change `Thread.Sleep` with `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is imitating long lasting operation. I'm not using Thread.Sleep in production code, there is an business logic instead of it. This problem appears for any async task.

Comment: @user3738114 I think you have misanderstanding what actually Thread.Sleep and Task.Run do.

Comment: @user3738114 if you want to do your long time operation in new thread, you should use new Thread(()=> {...some code}).Start()

Answer (score 0):

No that not the case. Its been pretending like this because both of the API's have same level of `thread.sleep` so its obvious that it will perform FIFO behavior i.e API hits first will response first

To verify this kindly set `Thread.Sleep(1)` for the second API during debugging and you will find out that second API will response before the response of first API.

You can also verify by placing a debugger and you will find out that second API will hit server as soon as you send request.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing [Threadpool starvation](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/threadpool_starvation.md). You start off with relatively few threads in your pool that can service requests. What you are doing is blocking a threadpool thread for 20 seconds, which means it is doing nothing for that period. When you hit that endpoint over and over, you will run into a situation where all your threads that can service requests are tied up, doing nothing but waiting.

To fix this, don't offload to a threadpool thread i.e. don't do `Task.Run()` and change to `await Task.Delay(20000)` for optimal throughput.

Answer (score -1):

You should do a more correct test, so only one of the methods is waiting.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NoWait()
    {
        return Content("1");
    }


    public async Task<int> SleepWait()
    {

        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(20000));

        return 2;
    }
}
```

Then call `SleepWait()` and right after `NoWait()`, what is the output then?